# How to make background of Files dark in iOS 17?

Tags: ios, files.app

When reading PDFs in Files in iOS 17, the background color (behind/around the PDF) is light gray, at least for white-page PDFs.

I mean the app's background, not the background of the pages of the PDF

How can I make it dark gray or black instead?

[image]

Comment: How would you read text if the background is black?

Comment: @nohillside I mean the app's background, not the background of the pages of the PDF. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: When do you even see that background? I usually have to zoom to screen width anyway to read the document.

Comment: @nohillside in PDFs with some landscape, some portrait pages, it is very obvious. In PDFs where all pages are same orientation and size, you can still see the background in the gaps between the pages

Answer (score 1):

Open system settings, search for dark (or appearance).

In the appearance select Dark and the non-document sections of the files app are dark.

Comment: It is already Dark

Comment: That's space rendered in the PDF, not the chrome or a part of the app, @theonlygusti Great edit with a photo to show what you're seeing, btw.

Comment: The gray background is part of the app, not the PDF. And in iOS 16 it used to be black or dark gray.